# How to get a jQuery item in a collection of selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to access a selector in my array:

```
<ul>
  <li class="elem">A</li>
  <li class="elem">B</li>
  <li class="elem">C</li>
</ul>

var $elems = $('li.elem');
console.log($elems[1].text()); /* jQuery method call */
```

I know there is the `get()` method, but it seems to be an implementation to se `[]` operator.
So what is the best way to access an item on a jQuery array?

Should we do something like `$($elems[1]).text()` ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: @elclanrs thanks it's the method i was looking for, maybe you could reply as an answer so i could valide it. Thanks again!

Comment: Look you select with `elams` but you gave class 'elam' to `li` elements

Answer (score 3):

Use method for get text [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('li.elem').eq(1).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using the [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

```
var $elems = $('li.elems');
console.log($elem.eq(0).text());
```

Since, eq() is zero based index, so eq(0) will give you the first li in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $elems = $('li.elems');
  console.log( $elems.eq(1).text() );
});
```

You should note that `get()` returns a DOM element while `eq()` returns a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

You could try followings ways

```
// jQuery Method call 
console.log( $($elems[1] ).text() ); 
console.log( $elems.filter(':eq(1)').text() );
console.log( $elems.eq(1).text() );

//native method
console.log( $elems[1].innerHTML );
```

All prints same results